# Going back to my headhunter to switch jobs?

Tags: recruitment, quitting

I recently got hired by a company through a recruiting agency, but I want to find another job.

I can get a new job through another agency, but I would like to keep a good relationship with the one that got me this job.

The agency has always told me to be very open with them, but should I tell them that I want to leave the new job or move jobs?

I think it would be actually dangerous for me. After all, it's the client that pays them. If the agency just got me another job, the company would be basically taken by surprise, and not use the headhunter anymore.

So I am under the impression that they would either want to "fix things" or just say "deal with it", where "fixing things" could actually get me fired - say they call my employer and tell him "Anthony feels that things are wrong, what to do?" The company feels I might leave and fires me.

So I thought to just call another headhunter and tell them to get me a new job, and when it's done, if the first headhunter calls me, tell them "I did not want to put you in a difficult position".

Is it the right choice?

Comment: It seems like you've already answered your own question - the recruiter won't do this because it will ruin their relationship.

Comment: Well, yes and no...the recruiter is the best game in town, and made a reputation for seriousness - still, I don't know what's the "standard behavior" in these cases.

Comment: In the past, I was placed by a recruiter, after 5 months, I did not feel that I fit with the employer culture. I called the same recruiter and he was happy to present me to another of his customer and get another commission. What I heard after, is if I called him before 3 months that I was hired, he would have to find another candidate freely for that employer. So if you like your recruiter and you think he does not have a personal bound with your current employer, I would call him again explaining the situation.

Comment: How long have you been at this position? It makes a huge difference in the calculus for the recruiter and how your current employer views them.

Comment: what sort of "headhunter" / agency  is this? are they also your employer and bondyshop you out

Comment: @PoloHoleSet 1 month

Comment: Why don´t you just seek a job for yourself? The reason why a company pays  a headhunter a (usually quite large) fee is they are not able to fill the position by themselves. If you are searching for a less stressful environment, you chances of finding that may be higher if you apply directly to companies/jobs that appeal to you.

Comment: I'll offer an answer based on that.

Comment: The agency told you to be open with them because they want to know what you're thinking. It doesn't necessarily mean they're going to help you, unless helping you would also be beneficial for them.

Comment: @Daniel Certainly a good idea.

Comment: @AffableAmbler Absolutely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can get a new job through another agency, but I would like to keep a
>   good relationship with the one that got me this job.

The problem with using the same agency is *they most likely are loyal to the money*, meaning the company that placed you.  There are plenty of headhunters/recruiters out there, **why not be safe and use a different one**?  This reduces your risk of the current employer *accidentally* finding out.

After you find another gig, and you find the relationship with the other recruiter is important to you, *call them up and explain* why you used another resource and express the desire to work together again in the future.

**Short answer**:  Use a different recruiter in your case.

Answer (score 1):

Since you indicated, in comments, that it's been a month, you should definitely seek another headhunter, if you're determined to do this. I did this for a living for a few years, so this is what my experience was -

1. The recruiter is going to want to have a happy customer who wants to continue to use his/her services. While they are helping you find a job, which is a huge thing to do, ultimately, the company pays their fees. The company is the customer. You are not. You are the product, and some recruiting firms emphasize looking at candidates strictly as commodities that produce revenue, sadly. Sounds like that's not the case with this recruiter, but the company is still the customer. Placing a candidate who doesn't stick around isn't going to make the client company feel like they are happy.... quite the opposite, so the recruiter is going to either try to discourage you from leaving. They will mention that job hopping doesn't look good, etc, which are valid points, but definitely for their own interests as much as yours. They might want to try and help resolve issues so you stay (as you wondered about in the question).  If you're determined to go, you won't find a willing ally.
2. The recruter who placed you stands to lose their fee, or have to replace for free (my agreements had a three or six month guarantee window, depending on what we negotiated. Had one customer who wanted a one year guarantee, and agreed to pay a higher fee in exchange for that).
3. The recruiter is almost definitely contractually prohibited from placing you or any other employees of that company elsewhere for some time period (my agreements had a 1 year moratorium for my paid clients).

Your previous headhunter will definitely be reluctant to help, in general, and may be contractually prevented from doing so. So, it may not even come down to you having that choice, but, regardless, you want someone strongly engaged and eager to find you a new position, which would be a different recruiter.

Just be aware, a new recruiter is going to look at you leaving this position with a little bit of "what if this happens with the position I place this person in?", possibly.  Be prepared to answer questions that will assure the next person that this was an incredibly unique situation that won't replicate itself, as opposed to a flight of whimsy (from their perspective).

Since you aren't asking about whether it's a good idea or not to leave, and we don't have any information on the exact circumstances, we won't explore those issues.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet super answer

Answer (score -4):

> I can get a new job through another agency, but I would like to keep a
>   good relationship with the one that got me this job.

Talk to your company.  They are in the consulting business. They understand that it doesn't always work out. If you have a good relationship with your company they will be able to get another job, and transition out of this one in a way that makes everyone happy.

In a worst case scenerio they tell you no they will not pull you out, but they are not going to tell their client until you give notice.  If you leave with out giving them a chance then you are rolling the dice on if you have a good relationship going forward.

Comment: *In a worst case scenario they tell you no they will not pull you out, but they are not going to tell their client until you give notice.*  You cannot guarantee that, heck I have seen major placement firms you have heard of do it in an effort to kiss the cash cows arce.  Dangerous advise in my experience.

Comment: It make me nervous man...if I get fired, I am in trouble, my bank account is in the red right now.

Comment: @AnthonyDuvall - Then why are you looking for a new job? It seems your priorities may be misplaced.

Comment: My priority is my health - stress here is very high. Why not do it if I can get a new job?

Comment: @AnthonyDuvall - Then explain that to your company.  They may be able to do something about some of the stressors.  If they have been good to you so far why would they stop now?  You are making money for them by working.  If they can transition you out in a way that makes everyone happy its in their best interest.  You can still make money for them why would they not try to make it work.

Comment: It's the part "make everyone happy" that scares me. To make everyone happy, they will have to explain to my company that they are in the process of pulling me out, otherwise they will be taken by surprise. I don't see a serious agency take its customers by surprise. And when (not if) they tell the company, my ass is grass.

Comment: @IDrinkandIKnowThings They have NOT been good to me - this is a sh*t job.

Comment: @AnthonyDuvall You said the goal was to keep a good relationship with them.  If you want out entirely just treat it like a business transaction.  Dont let any emotion into it from your end and any butthurt they have will fade away.

Comment: @AnthonyDuvall - As long as they tell the company about you leaving before they complain to the company about the work you are doing it will look like sour grapes to your company.